# Partial sum of harmonic series, every n is coprime to some k

Tags: sequences-and-series, analytic-number-theory

I am doing some analytic number theory and I'm strugling with showing this result in particular:

$\sum_{n\leq x,(n,k)=1}\frac{1}{n} = \frac{\phi(x)\log(x)}{k} + O(1)$

Where $k$ is some constant. In general, I am unsure how to approach series with the coprime requirement in the summation index. I have tried Abel Summation, re working indices, the usual number theory tricks. Any tips would be appreciated!

Comment: Can you show that $$\sum_{\substack{n \leqslant x \\ (n,k) = 1}} 1 = \frac{\phi(k)}{k}\cdot x + O(1)\,?$$ Then Abel summation is quick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using $\sum_{d | n} \mu(d) = 1_{n=1}$, $\sum_{d | k}\phi(d)= k \implies \phi(k) = \sum_{d | k}\mu(d) \frac{k}{d}$ and $\sum_{n \le x} \frac{1}{n}=\log(x)+\gamma+\mathcal{O}(1/x)$ we obtain
$$\sum_{n \le x, (n,k)=1} \frac{1}{n} = \sum_{d | k} \mu(d) \sum_{n \le x, d | (n,k)} \frac{1}{n} = \sum_{d | k} \mu(d) \sum_{n \le x/d} \frac{1}{nd}$$ 
$$=\sum_{d | k} \frac{\mu(d)}{d}  (\log x-\log d+\gamma+\mathcal{O}(d/x))= \frac{\phi(k)}{k}(\log x+\gamma)-\sum_{d | k} \frac{\mu(d)}{d} \log d+\mathcal{O}(\frac{\sigma_0(k)}{x})$$

Comment: I'm not sure I follow your manipulation of summation indices. I do believe that the sum is equal to $\sum_{n\leq x}(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{d|(n,k)}\mu (d))$ but once you start moving the indices I do not follow

Comment: @AndrewStasiuk $=\sum_{n\leq x}\sum_{d|(n,k)}\frac{1}{n}\mu (d)=\sum_{d|k}\sum_{n\leq x,d | (n,k)}\frac{1}{n}\mu (d)$ nothing complicated here